# Selecting Binned values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a data frame with few columns having binned value. Those binned values have been made using `pd.cut()` option.The datatypes for the columns are given by;

```
group_credit                                  object
group_transaction                             object
 dtype: object
```

As seen above there are two columns which have binned values, and I have converted them into strings for convenience. Then I am trying to subset few rows;

```
temp=fraud_data[fraud_data['group_transaction']=='[20,23)']
temp
```

But I am getting no data at all. This value is present in the data frame, as shown below:

```
fraud_data.head(4)
```

This code gives the very first row as the following;

```
group_credit| group_transaction
[1500,2000)    [20,23)
```

Can I kindly get some help on how to subset for binned values, which are already transformed to strings?thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to convert them to a string; leave them as `category`.

With only one `Interval` it often makes sense to set it as the index. Then you can use `.loc` to slice intervals by selecting any value within that interval:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.randint(1,10,15)})
df['my_bin'] = pd.cut(df.data, bins=3)

                           # Could use anything within the bin.
df.set_index('my_bin').loc[1.14123123]
#                data
#my_bin              
#(0.992, 3.667]     2
#(0.992, 3.667]     3
#(0.992, 3.667]     1
#(0.992, 3.667]     2
#(0.992, 3.667]     3
#(0.992, 3.667]     1
```

Without setting the index, it's possible to use `item in Interval` with a list comprehension to generate a Boolean mask, which easily extends to selecting on multiple Interval columns:

```
df[[1.14123123 in x for x in df.my_bin]]
```

---

Since you have multiple Intervals you could use the `label`. This makes sense if you want deciles, so your labels would be the integers 0-9. You can either provide your own labels, or with `False` it returns an integer label. (Here I'll leave both category labels in for illustration, but in practice you only need one.)

```
df['my_bin2'] = pd.cut(df.data, bins=3, labels=False)
df[df.my_bin2 == 0]
#    data          my_bin  my_bin2
#1      2  (0.992, 3.667]        0
#2      3  (0.992, 3.667]        0
#5      1  (0.992, 3.667]        0
#7      2  (0.992, 3.667]        0
#10     3  (0.992, 3.667]        0
#12     1  (0.992, 3.667]        0
```

We return the same subset, and see the labeling is sorted (The 0 label is the Interval with the smallest values).

Alternatively, `pandas._libs.interval.Interval`s have category codes, allowing you to keep the Interval and all of it's functionality but select them based on the category code. Like with the above you'd need knowledge of which codes select which bins:

```
df[df.my_bin.cat.codes == 0]
#    data          my_bin
#1      2  (0.992, 3.667]
#2      3  (0.992, 3.667]
#5      1  (0.992, 3.667]
#7      2  (0.992, 3.667]
#10     3  (0.992, 3.667]
#12     1  (0.992, 3.667]
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. So does it mean we can filter only on basis of labels, not the column `my_bin`.Kindly clarify

Comment: @jayant if you keep it a `category` then you can filter the category using the `category.codes` values, like in my last example, while still keeping the category as the value stored in the column. You can see I filter on the code being == 0, yet the value in the column is still `Interval(0.992, 3.667]`